# Identifying pcb component

Tags: components

Could somebody tell me what this item is please. It is black, circular about 6mm diameter and 2mm thick in this case. It has two leads which are soldered to the two opposing flat sides. It is part of a solid state ignition system

Comment: Impressively you already have an answer, but pics or it didn't happen!  Add an image of the component in question for best possible results.

Answer (score 2):

> *It is black, circular about 6mm diameter and 2mm thick in this case.*

If it looks like one of these: -

[image]

...then it's probably a [disc thermistor](https://www.ametherm.com/thermistor/disc-and-chip-ntc-thermistors) of some type but, it could also be an MOV transient voltage clamper or maybe an inrush current limiter like [this](https://www.ametherm.com/ptc-thermistors-vs-ntc-thermistors-for-inrush-current): -

[image]

It's still a disc thermistor as per the top picture but more modern devices fully encapsulate the soldered lead to prevent corrosion.

Comment: Aha thank you, an NTC, it's not got encapsulated leads which rather foxed me. Thanks Andy

Comment: @perplexed do you know what to do next to close down the question or are you waiting for more answers?